# [MongoDB]: Edit a value without reset another

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a object:

```
Options: {
  Obj_1: {
    Str_1: 'string'
  },
  Obj_2: {
    Str_2: 'string'
  }
}
```

i trying edit `Str_1` inside of `Obj_1`, this way:

```
const edit = { $set: { Options: { Obj_1: { Str_1: 'new value!' } } } }
await <database>.findOneAndUpdate(<queue>, edit, {new:true})
```

but that removes the `Obj_2`, someone know a solution?

Comment: Try `{ $set: { "Options.Obj_1.Str_1": 'new value!' } }`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const Options = {
    Obj_1: {
      Str_1: "string",
    },
    Obj_2: {
      Str_2: "string",
    },
  };

  const edit = {
    $set: {
      Options: {
        ...Options,
        Obj_1: { Str_1: "new value!" },
      },
    },
  };

  console.log({ edit });
```